# HOW TO: Insert checked checkboxes into mysql using C#

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, checkbox

I have a small WPF application, that doesn't works. It is connected to a mysql database. What I want to do is to be able to check several options in my wpf (using checkboxes), and to store those selected in my database.

Here's my sql code:

```
create table ejemploc
(
id int not null,
nombre varchar(35),
opcion1 boolean,
opcion2 boolean,
opcion3 boolean,
constraint pkid primary key (id)
)engine=innodb;
```

And my c# code:

```
conexion.Open();
            try
            {
                //I don't know what to put here
                cmd.CommandText = "insert into ejemploc values ('"+textBox1.Text+"', '"+textBox2.Text+"', '"++"', '"++"', '"++"')";
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cmd.Clone();
                MessageBox.Show("Datos Guardados", "Mensaje");
                conexion.Close();
                CargaDataGridView();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
```

Thank you very much for any answer!

**EDIT:**

The answer is to change both codes:

```
create table ejemploc
(
id int not null,
nombre varchar(35),
opcion1 varchar(5),
opcion2 varchar(5),
opcion3 varchar(5),
constraint pkid primary key (id)
)engine=innodb;
```

it changed from boolean to varchar(5)

and my c# code changed to:

```
"insert into ejemploc values ('" + textBox1.Text + "', '" + textBox2.Text + "', '" + checkBox1.Checked.ToString() + "', '" + checkBox2.Checked.ToString() + "', '" + checkBox3.Checked.ToString() + "')";
```

Thanks @Thomas Fanley for your anwser :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just try `(CheckBox.Checked).ToString()`. This will return true / false depending on if it's checked or not.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @Thomas Farley. It kinda works, it saves, but it saves everything as false, whether it's checked or no.

Comment: Sure! conexion.Open();
            try
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "insert into ejemploc values ('"+textBox1.Text+"', '"+textBox2.Text+"', '" +(checkBox1.Checked).ToString()+"', '"+(checkBox2.Checked).ToString()+"', '"+(checkBox3.Checked).ToString()+"')";
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cmd.Clone();
                MessageBox.Show("Datos Guardados", "Mensaje");
                conexion.Close();
                CargaDataGridView();
            }

Comment: I'm sorry, i'm a noob here. but basically it's; "insert into ejemploc values ('"+textBox1.Text+"', '"+textBox2.Text+"', '" +(checkBox1.Checked).ToString()+"', '"+(checkBox2.Checked).ToString()+"', '"+(checkBox3.Checked).ToString()+"')";

Comment: Okay, just off the back you don't need to surround your checkBox1.Checked with parenthesis, I shouldn't have done that in my answer. What event are you putting this in? And you're sure you're checking the boxes **before** inserting the data into the database?

Comment: Don't worry, i appreciate the help. I'm putting this in my button1_click event. And I'm pretty sure I'm checking the boxes before inserting the data. @Thomas Farley

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is then; If you run your own tests in a blank project it will display true / false depending on if it's checked or not. Are the database rows you're trying to insert the data in configured as Booleans? If so, change them to strings.

Comment: Well, I'll start all over again, then. Thanks for your help. And yes, the database rows are configured as boolean, just like my sql code says.

Comment: Well they shouldn't be; change them to strings. I'm pretty sure that will fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Bad code. Use params.

Example:

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO myTable VALUES(NULL, @number, @text)";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@number", 1);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@text", "One");
```